# Custom Source Model Attribute's Label is Indexed Incorrectly

Tags: product, indexing, source-model, flat-indexer

I have an `int`/`select` attribute with a custom source model. Most things (admin, attribute save/load, indexing option IDs, filtering in layered nav, etc.) work fine. One of the things that's not working is the option texts (column `my_attribute_value` that's indexed in `catalog_product_flat`.

While the option IDs are correctly indexed, the label is pulled from the `eav_attribute_option_value` table, instead of my custom source table.

My custom source class extends `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table` and I've rewritten the relevant methods to work with my custom source for option IDs and labels. I've having trouble locating the methods responsible for writing data to the flat tables.

Any ideas?

Update:

I'm having this problem because my custom-source option IDs don't have the correct labels indexed in `eav_attribute_option_value.value`. Instead of the labels from the custom table, it's getting the labels from the regular EAV tables at the time of indexing the attributes. I've actually had this issue before, and it required rewriting the attribute indexing process.

Comment: You will find them here: http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve isn't supported by magento.